# Calling a jQuery function twice (two elements) only processes the second call

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

I created a function and attempted to call it to modify two elements using two separate calls, but the second call is the only one that is triggered. If I reverse the order of the two, the second one is still the only one processed. The function is below.

It checks to see if elements are overlapping one another and changes the classes accordingly. See the function call in the window scroll function to see the two calls.

What am I doing wrong here?

Thank you!

```
$(function() {

    var checkOverlap = function(element) {
        if($(element).length) {
            var results = $(element).overlaps(".four_img, .full_img, .prod, .image_wide, .media-vimeo-video");

             $(element).removeClass('overlap');
              clearTimeout($.data(this, 'scrollTimer'));

              $.data(this, 'scrollTimer', setTimeout(function() {
                  // do something
                  if (results.length > 0) {
                    //console.log('something is overlapping');
                    $(element).addClass('overlap');
                  }

                  //console.log("Haven't scrolled in 500ms!");
              }, 500));


              //hide for sure if over related proejcts
              var footerOverlap = $(element).overlaps(".related");
              if (footerOverlap.length > 0) {
                //console.log('something is overlapping');
                $(element).addClass('footer-overlap');
              } else {
                $(element).removeClass('footer-overlap');
              }
        }
     }


      //side menu overlay
        $(window).scroll(function() {
            checkOverlap($(".close_share"));
            checkOverlap($('.animate_number'));
        });


  })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try storing the timer reference on the element,

```
clearTimeout(element.data('scrollTimer'));
element.data('scrollTimer', setTimeout(function() {
    if (results.length > 0) {
        $(element).addClass('overlap');
    }
}, 500));
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It makes perfect sense. I was not thinking about the fact that the timeout was cleared on each scroll.

Answer (score 0):

try to replace `this` with `$element`

```
$(function() {

    var checkOverlap = function( $element ) {
        if ( $element.length ) {
            var results = $element.overlaps(".four_img, .full_img, .prod, .image_wide, .media-vimeo-video");

             $element.removeClass('overlap');
              // replace `this` with $element
              //clearTimeout($.data(this, 'scrollTimer'));
              clearTimeout($.data( $element, 'scrollTimer'));

              // replace `this` with $element
              //$.data(this, 'scrollTimer', setTimeout(function() {
              $.data( $element, 'scrollTimer', setTimeout(function() { 
                  // do something
                  if (results.length > 0) {
                    //console.log('something is overlapping');
                    $element.addClass('overlap');
                  }

                  //console.log("Haven't scrolled in 500ms!");
              }, 500));


              //hide for sure if over related proejcts
              var footerOverlap = $element.overlaps(".related");
              if (footerOverlap.length > 0) {
                //console.log('something is overlapping');
                $element.addClass('footer-overlap');
              } else {
                $element.removeClass('footer-overlap');
              }
        }
     }


      //side menu overlay
        $(window).scroll(function() {
            checkOverlap($(".close_share"));
            checkOverlap($('.animate_number'));
        });


  })
```

Comment: I implemented the code below and it worked, but this one looks like it would work as well. Thank you!

Comment: @user1136510 - You're welcome! A little tip: don't use $( element ) every time you want to refer to an jQuery object, store it to a variable instead and then use the variable, it will be faster ;-)

Answer (score 0):

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
            checkOverlap($(".close_share, .animate_number"));
        });
```

Try this